# Using JS to submit a form with Custom HTTP Headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, http-headers

I need to submit a form and include some custom http headers with the request (the API requires them).

Something like jQuery.ajax() works great (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I can use the beforeSend arg to compose some headers.

However I need this for a synchronous request, to direct the browser to the destination of the form. So one of the following two would work, but I'm not sure if a solution exists.

1. Have JS create and submit a form. How do I include custom http headers in a form?
2. Find an equivalent function to jQuery.ajax(), that will submit a synchronous request.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.ajax` has a property `async` which can be set to `true` or `false`.

async false would make it a synchronous request.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified - needed it to be synchronous and take the user to that page in the same window, like the behavior of a regular form. I'll edit the question to clarify.